# How to "find" sequence element and predicate result at once?

Tags: scala, find, scala-collections

Suppose I have a function `f(n:Int):Option[String]`. I would like to find such `1 <= k <= 10` that `f(k)` is not `None`. I can code it as follows:

```
(1 to 10).find(k => f(k).isDefined)
```

Now I would like to know *both* `k` and `f(k)`.

```
val k = (1 to 10).find(f(_).isDefined)
val s = f(k)
```

Unfortunately, this code invokes `f(k)` twice. How would you find `k` and `f(k)` at once ?

Comment: Do you need only the first match or all matches that satisfy the predicate?

Comment: @huynhjl I need only one the first match (exactly what find does)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first try would be:

```
(1 to 10).view map {k => (k, f(k))} find {_._2.isDefined}
```

The use of `view` avoids creating intermediate `map`. Or even better with pattern matching and partial function:

```
(1 to 10).view map {k => (k, f(k))} collectFirst {case (k, Some(v)) => (k, v)}
```

This returns `Option[(Int, java.lang.String)]` (`None` if no element satisfying `f` is found).

You might also experiment with `.zipWithIndex`.

Comment: Thanks. I like both solutions but I do not see why the latter is better. Could you elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: I believe it is more idiomatic. Instead of imperative `isDefined` you are using pattern matching: "*find the first element in the sequence that matches given pattern)*".

Comment: Plus, it binds `v` to an actual inner value, so you'll get an `Option[(K, V)]` instead of `Option[(K, Option[V])]`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter - just map and find:

```
// for testing
def f (n: Int): Option [String] = 
  if (n > 0) Some ((List.fill (n) ("" + n)).mkString) else None

(-5 to 5).map (i => (i, f(i))).find (e => e._2 != None) 

// result in REPL
res67: Option[(Int, Option[String])] = Some((1,Some(1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more verbose version of Tomasz Nurkiewicz's solution:

```
xs = (1 to 10).view      
xs zip { xs map { f(_) } } collectFirst { case (k, Some(v)) => (k, v) }
```